# Highlight points in Matplotlib line plot with index as datetime

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, datetime, plot

I am trying to mark data points in the line plot using `markevery` option in matplotlib. I am plotting data with index in datetime format. When I create a list for the markevery I get this error

```
markevery=['13:15:00', '13:30:00', '13:45:00', '14:00:00', '14:15:00', '14:30:00'] is iterable but not a valid numpy fancy index
```

My code

```
markers_on= ['13:15:00','13:30:00','13:45:00','14:00:00','14:15:00','14:30:00']

ax1 = plt.subplot()

ax1.plot(data,'-gD', markevery=markers_on)

ax1.set_xlabel("Time (HH:MM:SS)",fontsize=15)
ax1.set_ylabel("Temp",fontsize=15)
```

My data looks like this:

| time | temp |
| --- | --- |
| 09:59:45 | 0.011154 |
| 10:00:00 | 0.028380 |
| 10:00:15 | 0.072002 |
| 10:00:30 | 0.151146 |
| 10:00:45 | 0.200887 |

How can I use list of datetime index to mark on the plot?

I have tried to convert the values in the list to datetime objects, but did not work.

Comment: I think you don't understand what markevery does. It is not clear to me what you are trying to achieve. I recommend taking a look at the documentation (https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/markevery_demo.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use [pandas.Index.get_indexer](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html#pandas.Index.get_indexer) to convert your list of strings `markers_on` to a list of positions where the index matches the target values:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# make data
d = {'time': ['09:59:45','10:00:00','10:00:15','10:00:30','10:00:45'],
    'temp': [0.011154, 0.028380, 0.072002, 0.151146, 0.200887]}

# make a data frame
data = pd.DataFrame(d, index=d['time'])

# a couple of timestamp strings to set markers at 
markers_on = ['10:00:15', '10:00:45']

# plot data, showing markers only for the specified timestamp strings
ax = plt.subplot()
ax.plot(data['time'], data['temp'], '-gD', markevery=data.index.get_indexer(markers_on))
ax.set_xlabel('Time (HH:MM:SS)', fontsize=15)
ax.set_ylabel('Temp', fontsize=15)
plt.show()
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
markers_on= ['13:15:00','13:30:00','13:45:00','14:00:00','14:15:00','14:30:00']
```

To

```
markers_on = [data.index.get_loc(marker) for marker in ['13:15:00','13:30:00','13:45:00','14:00:00','14:15:00','14:30:00']]
```

This way you get the indices corresponding to the specified times.